# Ruby on Rails - Passing date from text_field to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to send a date from a text_field into a controller. In the view I have this

```
<%= link_to 'Click me', :url => {:controller => 'test', :action => 'action', :submit => 'field_to_submit', :method => :post, :remote => true} %>

<%= form_tag(my_path, :method => "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Choose date:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("New Date") %>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller I have this:

```
def action
    if(params.has_key?(:q))
      @temp=params[:q]
    end
...
```

The problem is that if I put, for example, 2014-01-20 in the text_field I will get 1993 in the @temp variable. Meaning, instead of passing the date as a string (what I want, so I can use it latter) it interpretes the "-" as an operation and gives me the result.

Any way I can correct that?

Thanks!

Comment: can you print the params the controller receives to log (e.g `logger.info params` to know what the controller gets

Answer (score 1):

Maybe parse that string with:

```
> DateTime.parse(params[:q]) # if params[:q] is a date
=> Mon, 20 Jan 2014 00:00:00 +0000
```

Then you can handle it appropriately.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? If you w'd pass `nil`, you w'd get `TypeError`, if it w'd be some wrong string you w'd receive `ArgumentError` `invalid date` but nothing...?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `strptime`

```
DateTime.strptime("2014-01-20","%Y-%m-%d")
#=> #<DateTime: 2014-01-20T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456678j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: What do you mean it returns nothing? It returns a date or an `ArgumentError` but it will not return nothing. Ruby never returns nothing and strptime will not return nil. So please explain further.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing ERB is evaluating the string supplied before it is sent to the controller so you might try the below:

```
<%= link_to 'Click me', :url => {:controller => 'test', :action => 'action', :submit =>     'field_to_submit', :method => :post, :remote => true} %>

<%= form_tag(my_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Choose date:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q).to_s %>
  <%= submit_tag("New Date") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work. It still returns 1993 (using the example in the OP).